# WooCommerce: Remove schema.org on related products

Tags: php, wordpress

woocommerce adds the schema.org informations not only to the product itself, but also on the related products. So you get some errors according to the google schema.org test tool. how can I remove this schema.org informations on related products?

this part of the price.php shouln't load on related products:

```
    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_display_price() ); ?>" />
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() ); ?>" />
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code you don't want is showing up in price.php, perhaps you should override that with your own copy in your template/woocommerce folder. For more details on how this is accomplished, read WooCommerce's docs here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Of course, but I want to show the informations in the price.php, but not in the related products. The related products are using price.php and the products itself also. I need to seperate this. But I don't know how...

Comment: Ah, in that case you'd probably have to edit the single-product/related.php template, so that it loads a customized version of the price.php template rather than the base one. You could copy price.php to price-related.php or something, strip out the schema stuff, and then load price-related in your theme instead of price.php.